# Why another login is required for http://data.stackexchange.com/, when I've already logged into Stack Overflow with the same OpenID

Tags: support, data-explorer, login, openid

I use the same OpenID to log onto SO sites. When I log in to http://stackoverflow.com, and then navigate to other site such as http://meta.stackoverflow.com, it recognizes the same OpenID.

But when I open http://data.stackexchange.com, it shows login link on the top bar, I'm required to enter the same login credentials aagain. Why is this behavior with http://data.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data.SE is based on an entirely separate open source code base. This is different from the SE Network which is built on a proprietary code base.

Hence, your login data and account credentials are not shared between the two sites.

Comment: It also hasn't been updated in forever... Hint hint, SE team.

Comment: "not shared between the two sites", at least until you _do_ log in: then it can determine your UserId on any SE site.